# How to use Microsoft PowerToys PowerRenamer tool to strip the last N characters of a file name?

Tags: windows-10, powertoys

I have multiple files with different names that are of different length. This time, I want to use Powertoys PoweRenamer to strip specifically the last 12 characters of each file name. For this particular set of files, those last 12 characters are all different on all the files with the exception of the first character that is a dash or minus sign (-), in all of them, but I also will like to know what expression I have to use if in the future I need to strip a different number of characters with no character in common.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the file name but want to keep the file extensions, you can try the following:

- Search for: `.{12}(\..+)`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Check `Use Regular Expressions`

The above applies to Filename + Extension. If it should apply to Filename only, set the criteria to the following:

- Search for: `.{12}$`
- Replace with: Leave empty
- Check `Use Regular Expressions`

Change the `12` to the number of characters you want to remove.

**Filename + extension**
[image: Power Rename - Regex query & Results for filename + extension]

**Filename only**
[image: Power Rename - Regex query & Results for filename only]

Comment: I type exactly what you told me with your filename structure and with filename that have a structure that resembles more closely the filenames that I have, and it didn't work.

Comment: @3d1l What was the result when you tried? Share a picture.

Comment: https://imgur.com/qdLQoeO

Comment: @3d1l See edit.